# el navegador no reconoce la libreria socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

estaba haciendo una aplicacion que se conecta desde una pagina web a un servidor socket. Resulta que cuando ejecuto la pagina web el navegador no es capaz de encontrar la libreria socket.io

Codigo navegador index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <title>My Aplicación con Sockets</title>
          <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
          <script src="main.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <h1>My App</h1>
          <div id="messages"></div>
          <br/>
          <form onsubmit="return addMessage(this)">
            <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="titulo de notificacion" >
            <input type="text" id="body" placeholder="cuerpo de la notificacion">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar!">
          </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

en el codigo javascript del navegador me da problema con esta linea

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080', { 'forceNew': true });
```

el navegador muestra el siguiente error : GET http://localhost:8888/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Eso es que no estan enlazando bien el script en la página con `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` Podria ser que sobrará la primera /

Comment: y porque no usas la nativa de JavaScript?

Comment: el codigo fue adaptado de otro que consegui, pero de todas formas como seria la nativa ?

Comment: aqui tienes un [ejemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/WebSockets-840092-dup/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications)

Comment: Dentro de tu servidor, ¿donde se encuentra la libraria socket.io.js ?

Comment: en un subdirectorio atravez de npm descargado en un modulo